# laravel join subquery on condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have two kind of product. **game** and **game-time**.

in my code. `item_id` column of `order_items` table , represents the id of target product (may be id of `game_codes` or `game_time_codes`)

and `product_type_id` represents the id of product kind (number 1 for gameCode and 2 for gametime )

in my code im trying to show specific user orders with purchased items info.

i should join `game_codes` when if product_type_id is 1

and join `game_time_codes` when if product_type_id is 2

i wrote this query but it return null. how can i fix this?

```
$joinGCSub = DB::table("game_codes")->where("user_id", 1)->where("sold", 1);
$joinGTSub = DB::table("game_time_codes")->where("user_id", 1)->where("sold", 1);

   $orders = DB::table('orders')
      ->leftJoin("order_items", "orders.id", "=", "order_items.order_id")
      ->leftJoin("product_types", "order_items.product_type_id", "=", "product_types.id")
      ->joinSub($joinGCSub, "gc" , function ($join){
         $join->on('order_items.item_id', "=", "gc.id")->where("product_types.id", 1);
      })->joinSub($joinGTSub, "gt", function($join) {
         $join->on('order_items.item_id', "=", "gt.id")->where("product_types.id", 2);
      })
      ->where("orders.user_id", 1)
      ->get();


   dd($orders);
```

you can see tables structure below

order TABLE

```
id | user_id | .... etc
```

order_items table TABLE

```
id | order_id | product_type_id | item_id ...etc
```

game_codes TABLE

```
id | code | user_id | sold ... etc
```

game_time_codes TABLE

```
id | code | user_id | sold ...etc
```

Comment: you forgot the` get()` at the end of `$joinGCSub = DB::table("game_codes")->where("user_id", 1)->where("sold", 1);
$joinGTSub = DB::table("game_time_codes")->where("user_id", 1)->where("sold", 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Can write like below:

```
$joinGCSub = DB::table("game_codes")->where("user_id", 1)->where("sold", 1);
    $joinGTSub = DB::table("game_time_codes")->where("user_id", 1)->where("sold", 1);

    $query = DB::table('orders')
        ->leftJoin("order_items", "orders.id", "=", "order_items.order_id")
        ->leftJoin("product_types", "order_items.product_type_id", "=", "product_types.id");
    if ($product_type_id == 1)
        $query->joinSub($joinGCSub, "gc", function ($join) {
            $join->on('order_items.item_id', "=", "gc.id")->where("product_types.id", 1);
        });
    if ($product_type_id == 2)
        $query->joinSub($joinGTSub, "gt", function ($join) {
            $join->on('order_items.item_id', "=", "gt.id")->where("product_types.id", 2);
        });

    $orders = $query->where("orders.user_id", 1)
        ->get();


    dd($orders);
```

**But it's better to use `whereExist`**

Comment: in your query you dont have `$product_type_id`  because it comes from order_items table. we shoud check `order_items.product type id` value on the query first. can you please write 'whereExist' approach?